# Modal scrollable content don't scroll and footer is hidden

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm doing a web application in **Angular 8.0.4** and I'm using **@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap 5.0.0-rc.0**.

I'm following the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) to create a **Modal with scrollable content**. Right now, the content don't scroll and the footer is hidden.

I'm open the Modal like this:

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalInventoryComponent, {
      size: 'xl',
      scrollable: true
    });
```

Modal template:

```
<div class="modal-header d-flex justify-content-between">

  <h4 class="modal-title">{{mySupermarket.name}}</h4>

  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>

</div>

<div class="modal-body">

  <!-- I have 4 Tables like this one -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      Example
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h6>Product</h6>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let inv of inventories">
              <th scope="row">{{inv.number}}</th>
              <td>{{inv.name}}</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('close click')">Cerrar</button>
</div>
```

I have tried in my component css:

```
.modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I saw solutions where they add a fixed height with CSS but, I have 4 long tables and I would like the modal to have much height as possible.

Demo on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufnwbh

What I'm missing? The example in the documentation works fine.

My goal is to have a Modal with scrollable content only, with the header and footer fixed/static, as the example in the documentation.

Comment: can you create a working `stackblitz`

Comment: Hi @Aravind, I have added the link of stackblitz in my message.